# Create custom Pod which uses external Pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am just about figuring my way around creating and publishing pods.

I have created a Pod and I would like my Pod to make use of an external pod, in my case, SnapKit.

I understand that there is a *Podfile* to the Pod_Example target. Although when I am developing in my class files under

```
Pod/Classes/File.swift
```

and when I try to import

```
import SnapKit
```

I get the error

```
No such module SnapKit
```

How can I use an external pod in the development of my pod ?

Answer (score 1):

Place the dependencies in `Pod.podspec` file. For example:

`s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'`

Then do `pod install` and the library should be available.